# Extra White Space on my DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, file, datagrid

I dont Know Why I am getting this extra white space on my grid, I have checked the file from where I am reading to database and cant find anything wrong. Anyone has got a clue of why I am getting this?(3rd row )Seems like is adding extra space when I have more than 1 row in file
[image: Extra white space]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Has 1017291 got a stray \n at the start?

Comment: Have you looked whether it is a vertical alignment?

Comment: @ Twelve47 noo I think I am going to work around and trim that what space.

Comment: @username and @Twelve47 I can see its because its adding on my database with that Space thats y is showing that space but I am wondering why is doing that

Comment: @Twelve47 you are right is because of \n Thank u!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is likely to be a problem with your dataset you could use a value converter, eg:

```
public class TrimWhiteSpaceValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
                if (value == null)
                {
                        return null;
                }
                return value.ToString().Trim();
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
                if (value == null)
                {
                        return null;
                }
                return value.ToString().Trim();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a converter, to filter string before showing them.